# Create heatmap and plot three different lines on top of it ,based on label

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, line-plot

I have the following dataframe:

```
val1=np.random.rand(234)
val2=np.random.rand(234)
val3=np.random.rand(234)
wave=np.arange(start=300, stop=1000, step=3)
labels=['label1','label2','label3']

df=pd.DataFrame([val1,val2,val3],columns=wave)
df['labels']=['label1','label2','label3']
df=df.set_index('labels')
```

And the following line:

```
line=np.random.uniform(low=-1.5, high=1.5, size=(234,))
line_df=pd.DataFrame([wave,line]).T
line_df.columns=['wave','val']
```

I want to create heatmap with the labels and to plot in each label row the line,as secondary axis, something like this:
[image]

I have draw here the line on top of the heatmap (theortically suppose to be the same line).

I could create the heatmap this way but not to draw the line per label:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(25,8.7)},font_scale = 2)
ax =sns.heatmap(df,cmap='Reds').set(title='heatmap')

ax2=plt.twinx()
ax2.plot(line_df['wave'], line_df['val'],color="blue",linewidth=3)
```

Looking for ideas to add the same line per y label.

Comment: An idea is to create 3 subplots with shared x and zero distance between them. That way you can have 3 different y-axes at the right.   (Also note that `ax=sns.heatmap(df,cmap='Reds').set(title='heatmap')` makes `ax` `None`. You need `ax =sns.heatmap(df,cmap='Reds')` and then `ax.set(title='heatmap')`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach creating 3 stacked subplots. Separate subplots allows for individual y-axes for the 3 curves.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

val1 = np.random.rand(234)
val2 = np.random.rand(234)
val3 = np.random.rand(234)
wave = np.arange(start=300, stop=1000, step=3)
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']

df = pd.DataFrame([val1, val2, val3], columns=wave)
df['labels'] = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
df = df.set_index('labels')

line = np.random.uniform(low=-1.5, high=1.5, size=(234,))
line_df = pd.DataFrame([wave, line]).T
line_df.columns = ['wave', 'val']

sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize': (25, 8.7)}, font_scale=2)
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0})
norm = plt.Normalize(df.to_numpy().min(), df.to_numpy().max())
cmap = 'Reds'
for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.imshow(df.iloc[i:i + 1, :].to_numpy(), extent=[wave[0], wave[-1], 0, 1], aspect='auto', cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
    ax.set_yticks([0.5])
    ax.set_yticklabels([df.index[i]])
    if ax == axs[1]:
        ax.set_ylabel('Label')
    ax2 = ax.twinx()
    ax2.plot(line_df['wave'], line_df['val'], color="blue", linewidth=3)
    ax.grid(False)
    ax2.grid(False)
axs[0].set_title('heatmap')
plt.colorbar(ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ax=axs)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, right=0.72)
plt.show()
```

[image: 3 heatmaps]